# SQL Visual Studio how to make outlining toggle box appear?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I write SQL code in visual studio.
One feature that is really helpful to me is the little minus box I can click to collapse my entire query into one line.

For example, I have the box on my insert statement which collapses pretty much the entire query.

[image: Collapsed]

As you can see, it collapses about 600 lines.

However, that is not the behaviour I want. Later on in my query there is a subquery that I want to collapse. However, no toggle box appears.

[image: Not Collapsed]

What determines where this box exists and how much code it collapse? Sometimes when I press an enter before the select line, it works, but this time it is not. I know I can do it manually by doing hide selection, but this goes away as soon as I close the file. What is the logic behind outlining?

Comment: That image doesn't look like a subquery; it's not contained in parentheses.

Comment: here is the full structure of the query, insert into ... select distinct... union select distinct... The insert into collapses but the individual select distinct don't. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: A statement that forms part of a `UNION` isn't a subquery. A subquery would be something like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable) T`. The `SELECT` statement inside the parenthesis is a subquery.

Comment: As a side comment, `UNION` removes duplicates, so you don't need to use `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

To collapse, it needs to be a complete block of code. Since a subquery is not a complete statement, it can't be collapsed.

It might also need to be properly indented and connected to a database.

Comment: That's true for it autodetecting collapsable areas, but you can still specify parts you want collapsable outside of this. See my answer below. You have to use the outlining menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the lines of SQL you want, then go to:

> Edit > Outlining > Hide Selection

Then this allows you to toggle hiding/showing other parts of your SQL.